# Add counts to geom_hex as labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add labels to geom_hex, which raises two questions:

1. how to I get their coordinates;
2. how do I extract their count value?

minimal example:

```
pipeline <- read.csv(url('http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7446674/pipeline.csv'),sep="\t",header=T)
pipeline <- pipeline[pipeline$Units>0,]

ggplot(pipeline,aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude))+
    #stat_density2d(n=25,aes(fill=..level..), geom="polygon") +
      geom_hex(bins=12)+
      coord_equal(ratio = 1/1)+
      theme_bw()+
      ggtitle('San Francisco Development Pipeline\nQ2 2013')
```

(Also, on the geom_hex, if anyone knows if weighs have been implemented yet I would be interested in knowing that, too)
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can label each bin with its count using:

```
ggplot(pipeline,aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude))+
  geom_hex(bins=12)+
  stat_binhex(aes(label=..count..), geom="text", bins=12, colour="white") +
  coord_equal(ratio = 1/1)+
  theme_bw()+
  ggtitle('San Francisco Development Pipeline\nQ2 2013')
```

(PS: was it the counts you wanted as labels? It seemed that way, but I wasn't entirely sure)

[image: Labelled counts]

Comment: Counts are good, unless I can weigh the observations with stat_binhex, but I don't think that is implemented yet.